# How to find the required credential properties for an AuthenticationKind

Tags: authentication, ssas, credentials, ssas-tabular

I'm using an application to deploy a tabular model to the MS analysis service through an SSIS package by using a tmsl script. This tabular model can have many data sources connected to that. So I'm using a wizard to get the authentication credentials from the user for each of these data sources. After obtaining the credentials from the user I'm creating another tmsl to update the tabular model with those credentials.

I want to find the required credential properties for each AuthenticationKind so that I can ask for input for those from the user.
Eg :-

AuthenticationKind = UsernamePassword, then the user has to provide both username & password

AuthenticationKind = Windows, then the user has to provide both username & password

If these required credential properties are not provided then the user will not be able to refresh/process this tabular model.

[AuthenticationKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.authenticationkind?view=analysisservices-dotnet) This link provides details about all AuthenticationKind constants that are available and this link provides details about [CredentialProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.credentialproperty?view=analysisservices-dotnet&source=docs) which are available.

Please help me find the required properties for each AuheticationKind as stated in the examples above.